# Multithread access to list C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, list

I have a task to show difference between syncronized and unsyncronized multithreading. Therefore I wrote an application simulating withdrawing money from clients' bank accounts. Each of some number of threads chooses a random user and withdraws money from the account. 
Every thread should withdraw every account once. First time the threads are syncronized, but the second time they are not. So there must be a difference between accounts, withdrawed by syncronized and unsyncronized threads. And the difference must be different for different numbers of users and threads. But in my application I have difference just for 1000 threads. So I need unsyncronized threads' results to be strongly different from syncronized threads' ones.
The class User:

```
public class User : IComparable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Start { get; set; }

    public int FinishSync { get; set; }

    public int FinishUnsync { get; set; }

    public int Hypothetic { get; set; }

    public int Differrence { get; set; }
...
}
```

The method which withdraws money:

```
public void Withdraw(ref List<User> users, int sum, bool isSync)
    {
        int ind = 0;
        Thread.Sleep(_due);
        var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        //used is list of users,  withrawed by the thread
        while (_used.Count < users.Count)
        {
            while (_used.Contains(ind = rnd.Next(0, users.Count))) ; //choosing a random user
            if (isSync) //isSync = if threads syncroized
            {
                if (Monitor.TryEnter(users[ind]))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        users[ind].FinishSync = users[ind].FinishSync - sum;
                    }

                    finally
                    {
                        Monitor.Exit(users[ind]);
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                lock (users[ind])
                {
                    users[ind].FinishUnsync = users[ind].FinishUnsync - sum;
                }
            }
            _used.Add(ind);
        }
        done = true;
    }
```

And the threads are created this way:

```
 private void Withdrawing(bool IsSync)
    {
        if (IsSync)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _num; i++)
            {
                _withdrawers.Add(new Withdrawer(Users.Count, _due, _pause));
                _threads.Add(new Thread(delegate()
 { _withdrawers[i].Withdraw(ref Users, _sum, true); }));
                _threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
                _threads[i].Start();
                _threads[i].Join();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < _num; ++i)
            {
                _withdrawers.Add(new Withdrawer(Users.Count, _due, _pause));
                _threads.Add(new Thread(delegate()
 { _withdrawers[i].Withdraw(ref Users, _sum, false); }));
                _threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
                _threads[i].Start();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've changed the     Withdraw    class this way, bc the problem could have been in creating threads separately from the delegate:

```
class Withdrawer
{
    private List<int>[] _used;
    private int _due;
    private int _pause;
    public int done;
    private List<Thread> _threads;
    public Withdrawer(List<User> users, int n, int due, int pause, int sum)
    {
        _due = due;
        _pause = pause;
        done = 0;
        _threads = new List<Thread>(users.Count);
        InitializeUsed(users, n);
        CreateThreads(users, n, sum, false);
        _threads.Clear();
        while (done < n) ;
        Array.Clear(_used,0,n-1);
        InitializeUsed(users, n);
        CreateThreads(users, n, sum, true);
    }

    private void InitializeUsed(List<User> users, int n)
    {
        _used = new List<int>[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            _used[i] = new List<int>(users.Count);
            for (int j = 0; j < users.Count; j++)
            {
                _used[i].Add(j);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateThreads(List<User> users, int n, int sum, bool isSync)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            _threads.Add(new Thread(delegate() { Withdraw(users, sum, isSync); }));
            _threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
            _threads[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void Withdraw(List<User> users, int sum, bool isSync)
    {
        int ind = 0;
        var rnd = new Random();
        while (_used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Count > 0)
        {
            int x = rnd.Next(_used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Count);
            ind = _used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)][x];
            if (isSync)
            {
                lock (users[ind])
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(_due);
                    users[ind].FinishSync -= sum;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(_due);
                users[ind].FinishUnsync -= sum;
            }
            _used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)][x] = _used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)][_used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Count - 1];
            _used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].RemoveAt(_used[int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name)].Count - 1);
            Thread.Sleep(_pause);
        }
        done++;
    }
}
```

Now the problem is FinishUnSync values are correct, while FinishSync values are absolutely not.
   Thread.Sleep(_due);
and
    Thread.Sleep(_pause);

are used to "hold" the resourse, bc my task is the thread should get resourse, hold it for a _due ms, and after processing wait _pause ms before finishing.

Comment: If you are writing code to show the difference is synchronous and asynchronous code but you have to artificially inflate the difference between the two methods, then your example is wrong.

Comment: I would suggest that unsynchronized access to non-threadsafe containers yield unpredictable results, which includes correct results sometimes.

Comment: Which version of the framework? .NET 4.5 brings new Thread-safe collection for concurrent access.

Comment: @Fals 4.0 added most of them actually.

Comment: Gusdor, can you give a piece of advice how to do it?

Comment: gap, the problem is they are always correct, unfortunately.

Comment: Your "synchronized" test isn't demonstrating multithreading at all. There's never more than one thread doing anything. When a background thread is running, the main thread is waiting and nothing else is running.

Comment: Is `_pause` the same as `IsSync`?

Comment: Jim, sure. I removed the "join" string.

Comment: Jim Rhodes, no. _pause is used for other purpose

Comment: You're synchronizing in both the "synchronized" an "unsynchronized" code. In the synchronized code, you are using the Monitor class and in the unsynchronized code you are using "lock". You need to remove the lock statement.

Comment: But the way you have it now, each thread only does one unique update; there's no chance for a synchronization problem. I think you need to re-think what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ Jim Mischel : can you give me a hint? Because i have absolutely no idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code isn't doing anything useful, and doesn't show the difference between synchronized and unsynchronized access. There are many things you'll need to address.

Comments in your code say that `_used` is a list of users that have been accessed by the thread. You're apparently creating that on a per-thread basis. If that's true, I don't see how. From the looks of things I'd say that `_used` is accessible to all threads. I don't see anywhere that you're creating a per-thread version of that list. And the naming convention indicates that it's at class scope.

If that list is not per-thread, that would go a long way towards explaining why your data is always the same. You also have a real race condition here because you're updating the list from multiple threads.

Assuning that `_used` really is a per-thread data structure . . .

You have this code:

```
        if (isSync) //isSync = if threads syncroized
        {
            if (Monitor.TryEnter(users[ind]))
            {
                try
                {
                    users[ind].FinishSync = users[ind].FinishSync - sum;
                }

                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(users[ind]);
                }
            }

        }
        else
        {
            lock (users[ind])
            {
                users[ind].FinishUnsync = users[ind].FinishUnsync - sum;
            }
        }
```

Both of these provide synchronization. In the `isSync` case, a second thread will fail to do its update if a thread already has the user locked. In the second case, the second thread will wait for the first to finish, and then will do the update. In either case, the use of `Monitor` or `lock` prevents concurrent update.

Still, you would potentially see a difference if multiple threads could be executing the `isSync` code at the same time. But you won't see a difference because in your synchronized case you never let more than one thread execute. That is, you have:

```
    if (IsSync)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _num; i++)
        {
            _withdrawers.Add(new Withdrawer(Users.Count, _due, _pause));
            _threads.Add(new Thread(delegate()
               { _withdrawers[i].Withdraw(ref Users, _sum, true); }));
            _threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
            _threads[i].Start();
            _threads[i].Join();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _num; ++i)
        {
            _withdrawers.Add(new Withdrawer(Users.Count, _due, _pause));
            _threads.Add(new Thread(delegate()
                { _withdrawers[i].Withdraw(ref Users, _sum, false); }));
            _threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
            _threads[i].Start();
        }
    }
```

So in the `IsSync` case, you start a thread and then wait for it to complete before you start another thread. *Your code is not multithreaded.* And in the "unsynchronized" case you're using a `lock` to prevent concurrent updates. So in one case you prevent concurrent updates by only running one thread at a time, and in the other case you prevent concurrent updates by using a `lock`. There will be no difference.

Something else worth noting is that your method of randomly selecting a user is highly inefficient, and could be part of the problem you're seeing. Basically what you're doing is picking a random number and checking to see if it's in a list. If it is, you try again, etc. And the list keeps growing. Quick experimentation shows that I have to generate 7,000 random numbers between 0 and 1,000 before I get all of them. So your threads are spending a huge amount of time trying to find the next unused account, meaning that they have less likelihood to be processing the same user account at the same time.

You need to do three things. First, change your `Withdrawl` method so it does this:

```
        if (isSync) //isSync = if threads syncroized
        {
            // synchronized. prevent concurrent updates.
            lock (users[ind])
            {
                users[ind].FinishSync = users[ind].FinishSync - sum;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // unsynchronized. It's a free-for-all.
            users[ind].FinishUnsync = users[ind].FinishUnsync - sum;
        }
```

Your `Withdrawing` method should be the same regardless of whether `IsSync` is true or not. That is, it should be:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < _num; ++i)
        {
            _withdrawers.Add(new Withdrawer(Users.Count, _due, _pause));
            _threads.Add(new Thread(delegate()
               { _withdrawers[i].Withdraw(ref Users, _sum, false); }));
            _threads[i].Name = i.ToString();
            _threads[i].Start();
        }
```

Now you always have multiple threads running. The only difference is whether access to the user account is synchronized.

Finally, make your `_used` list a list of indexes into the `users` list. Something like:

```
_used = new List<int>(users.Count);
for (int i = 0; i < _used.Count; ++i)
{
    _used[i] = i;
}
```

Now, when you select a user, you do this:

```
var x = rnd.Next(_used.Count);
ind = _used[x];
// now remove the item from _used
_used[x] = _used[_used.Count-1];
_used.RemoveAt(_used.Count-1);
```

That way you can generate all users more efficiently. It will take n random numbers to generate n users.

A couple of nitpicks:

I have no idea why you have the `Thread.Sleep` call in the `Withdraw` method. What benefit do you think it provides?

There's no real reason to pass `DateTime.Now.Millisecond` to the `Random` constructor. Just calling `new Random()` will use `Environment.TickCount` for the seed. Unless you really want to limit the seed to numbers between 0 and 1,000.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that it would be possible to exacerbate the effects by breaking the math portion of the code into multiple steps with delays between to simulate interruptions. For example, read the value of FinishSync, sleep, subtract sum, sleep, write new value to FinishSync.

Comment: William is right, but I removed it. I chaged 'Withdrawing' and 'Withdraw' methods exactly as you said, but still there is no difference between the results. A new list _used is created in 'Withdrawer' constructor. And every thread has its own withdrawer.

Comment: @harrr: It's probably deadlocking on `while (done < n);` because the compiler is optimizing and not re-loading the value of `done`. Change that line to `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) { threads[i].Join(); }`